# Limiting ssh user account only to access his home directory!

Tags: windows, ssh, copssh

By reading some [tutorials](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/37) online I used these commands:

> Make a local group: **net localgroup CopsshUsers /ADD**
>
> Deny access to this group at top level: **cacls c:\ /c /e /t /d CopsshUsers**
>
> Open access to the copSSH installation directory: **cacls copssh-inst-dir /c /e /t /r CopsshUsers**
>
> Add Copssh user to the group above: **net localgroup CopsshUsers mysshuser /add**

simply put these commands will try to create a usergroup that has no permission on your computer and it only have access to the copSSH Installation directory.

This is not true, since you cannot change the permission on your windows directory, the third command won't remove access to windows folder (it says access denied on his log).
Somehow I achieved that by [taking ownership](http://www.blogsdna.com/2173/add-take-ownership-option-in-right-click-context-menu-of-windows-7.htm) of Windows folder and then i execute the third command so CopsshUsers has no permissions on windows folder from now on.

Now i tried to SSH to the server and it simply can't login! this is kind of funny because with permission on windows directory you can login and without it you can't!! So if you CAN SSH to the server somehow you know that you have access to the windows directory! (Is this really true??)

Simple task: Limiting ssh user account only to access his home directory on WINDOWS and nothing else!

Guys please help!

Answer (score 1):

The second command (deny access to c:\) seems very scary to me.  You are denying members of this group all access to c:\ recursively.  Programs are going to be run with their credentials, and those programs (which probably reside on the c:\ drive) are going to need to load libraries located on the c:\ drive.  If you deny them access then they won't be able to load those libraries and the programs will fail to load.  I can't imagine why you would ever want to do this, and I can't imagine that anything would work right if you did.  If you insist on going this route I would try denying write access instead of all access; however, the default permissions should be adequate for this - members of the Users group are denied write access (or rather they are only granted read access).

Answer (score 0):

On Unix systems this can be achieved with a [`chroot`](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Chroot) jail. Looking for something similar on Windows I found this:

- http://www.winquota.com/wj/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/161507/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-to-chroot

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for, but maybe this helps?